# How to solve python IDLE getting opened when I run python script in PHP file? (Output is not getting printed in web page)

Tags: python, php, xampp, anaconda

I am trying to print the output of a python file in php.

I have two files in a folder -> index.php and cal.py

index.php file

```
    <?php
       echo shell_exec(__DIR__."/cal.py");
    ?>
```

cal.py

```
    print ("Hello")
```

The problem is when I run the php file using xampp, 'cal.py' is opening in my python idle (which is linked to anaconda) while the process in the browser continuously loading until I close the idle. Eventually I am not getting any output getting printed on the web page.

I searched many forums but couldn't find an answer. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: change `echo shell_exec(__DIR__."/cal.py"); ` to  `echo shell_exec('python '.__DIR__.'/cal.py'); `.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Idle is not opening but nothing is getting displayed now (just a blank page). I actually tried running python --version cmd in windows cmd prompt but it did not work. So I tried in anaconda cmd prompt then it worked. So, I am assuming I should add something like anaconda3 in the path but I am not sure what to do exactly.